# Smooth out drawn lines (Pencil-like tool) java

Tags: java, graphics

```
if ((e != null && l.size() > 0) && (l != null)) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size() - 1; i++) {
            Point p1 = l.get(i);
            Point p2 = l.get(i + 1);
            g.setColor(currentColor);
            g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
        }

        Point p3 = l.get(l.size() - 1);
        g.drawLine(p3.x, p3.y, e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y);
    }
```

I am creating a pencil-like tool in java and I'm having some problems when it comes to drawing the lines. It works as it should, but the lines are very edged and really not smooth at all.

I've looked into smoothing them by bezier things but that would be tricky for points close to one another. I just maybe want some form of line next to the one I have but with a lower alpha-value or something like that. That is the effect i'm after.

This is what it looks like now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUXRd.jpg

Comment: I've found this, it looks to be what i'm after, but i'm not sure how to download it and use :O https://javagraphics.java.net/doc/com/bric/geom/BasicMouseSmoothing.html

Comment: Perhaps on initial click down, you can draw a circle on the first point, and then draw a circle on every line end point after that to smooth out the edges at the end of the lines. A circle that's the same width as your brush/line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the problem you are running into is that you are preserving a little too much information.  You could certainly do some blurring or fattening of the line, which might help you to create a blurrier, fatter line, but I think that that would not actually help you to clean up the jitters.  My recommendation to make the lines look really nice would be a two step process.  The first process would be to use DP Line simplification to remove a lot of the slight jitters.  The second step of the process would be to use a Centripetal Catmull-Rom Spline in order to make the whole line flow like a very elegant curve.  The beauty of using this sort of spline for this purpose is that you don't need to do any serious work trying to figure out how to come up with all the control points that you would for doing Besier curves.  You can just use the original points plus two points at the start and end of your curve.

The Duglas-Peucker line simplifier is available in java using JTS from vivid solutions:
http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm

Here is the link to the Catmull-Rom code.
[Catmull-rom curve with no cusps and no self-intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489736/catmull-rom-curve-with-no-cusps-and-no-self-intersections/19283471#19283471)

Direct Drawing (jittery)

[image: Direct]

Simplified Drawing (Using JTS DP Line Simplification)

[image: Simple (just doing DP Line Simplification)]

Simplified and Smoothed using Centripetal Catmull-Rom

[image: DP + Centripetal Catmull-Rom]

Draw Panel Example Code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package demo;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.simplify.DouglasPeuckerSimplifier;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author hdunsford
 */
public class DrawPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private List<Coordinate> coords;

    /**
     * Creates new form DrawPanel
     */
    public DrawPanel() {
        initComponents();
        coords = new ArrayList<>();

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                coords.add(new Coordinate(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        try {
            super.paintComponent(g); // paint background
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            GeometryFactory f = new GeometryFactory();

            if (coords.size() < 2) {
                return;
            }
            LineString ls = f.createLineString(coords.toArray(new Coordinate[0]));
            //Geometry simple = ls;
            Geometry simple = DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(ls, 3.0);
            if (simple.getCoordinates().length < 2) {
                return;
            }
            List<Coordinate> raw = new ArrayList<>();
            raw.addAll(Arrays.asList(simple.getCoordinates()));
            List<Coordinate> spline = CatmullRom.interpolate(raw, 10);

            int[] xPoints = new int[spline.size()];
            int[] yPoints = new int[spline.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < spline.size(); i++) {
                xPoints[i] = (int) spline.get(i).x;
                yPoints[i] = (int) spline.get(i).y;
            }

            g2d.setColor(Color.red);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, xPoints.length);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DrawPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING:
     * Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the
     * Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Centripetal Catmull-Rom (tweaked to work with JTS Coordinate)

```
package demo;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author hdunsford
 */
public class CatmullRom {

    /**
     * This method will calculate the Catmull-Rom interpolation curve, returning it as a
     * list of Coordinate coordinate objects. This method in particular adds the first and
     * last control points which are not visible, but required for calculating the spline.
     *
     * @param coordinates The list of original straight line points to calculate an
     * interpolation from.
     * @param pointsPerSegment The integer number of equally spaced points to return along
     * each curve. The actual distance between each point will depend on the spacing
     * between the control points.
     * @return The list of interpolated coordinates.
     */
    public static List<Coordinate> interpolate(List<Coordinate> coordinates, int pointsPerSegment)
            throws Exception {
        List<Coordinate> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Coordinate c : coordinates) {
            vertices.add(new Coordinate(c.x, c.y));
        }
        if (pointsPerSegment < 2) {
            throw new Exception("The pointsPerSegment parameter must be greater than 2, since 2 points is just the linear segment.");
        }

        // Cannot interpolate curves given only two points.  Two points
        // is best represented as a simple line segment.
        if (vertices.size() < 3) {
            return vertices;
        }

        // Test whether the shape is open or closed by checking to see if
        // the first point intersects with the last point.  M and Z are ignored.
        boolean isClosed = vertices.get(0).x == vertices.get(vertices.size() - 1).x
                && vertices.get(0).y == vertices.get(vertices.size() - 1).y;
        if (isClosed) {
            // Use the second and second from last points as control points.
            // get the second point.
            Coordinate p2 = new Coordinate(vertices.get(1));
            // get the point before the last point
            Coordinate pn1 = new Coordinate(vertices.get(vertices.size() - 2));

            // insert the second from the last point as the first point in the list
            // because when the shape is closed it keeps wrapping around to
            // the second point.
            vertices.add(0, pn1);
            // add the second point to the end.
            vertices.add(p2);
        } else {
        // The shape is open, so use control points that simply extend
            // the first and last segments

            // Get the change in x and y between the first and second coordinates.
            double dx = vertices.get(1).x - vertices.get(0).x;
            double dy = vertices.get(1).y - vertices.get(0).y;

            // Then using the change, extrapolate backwards to find a control point.
            double x1 = vertices.get(0).x - dx;
            double y1 = vertices.get(0).y - dy;

            // Actaully create the start point from the extrapolated values.
            Coordinate start = new Coordinate(x1, y1);

            // Repeat for the end control point.
            int n = vertices.size() - 1;
            dx = vertices.get(n).x - vertices.get(n - 1).x;
            dy = vertices.get(n).y - vertices.get(n - 1).y;
            double xn = vertices.get(n).x + dx;
            double yn = vertices.get(n).y + dy;
            Coordinate end = new Coordinate(xn, yn);

            // insert the start control point at the start of the vertices list.
            vertices.add(0, start);

            // append the end control ponit to the end of the vertices list.
            vertices.add(end);
        }

        // Dimension a result list of coordinates. 
        List<Coordinate> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // When looping, remember that each cycle requires 4 points, starting
        // with i and ending with i+3.  So we don't loop through all the points.
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size() - 3; i++) {

            // Actually calculate the Catmull-Rom curve for one segment.
            List<Coordinate> points = interpolate(vertices, i, pointsPerSegment);
            // Since the middle points are added twice, once for each bordering
            // segment, we only add the 0 index result point for the first
            // segment.  Otherwise we will have duplicate points.
            if (result.size() > 0) {
                points.remove(0);
            }

            // Add the coordinates for the segment to the result list.
            result.addAll(points);
        }
        return result;

    }

    /**
     * Given a list of control points, this will create a list of pointsPerSegment points
     * spaced uniformly along the resulting Catmull-Rom curve.
     *
     * @param points The list of control points, leading and ending with a coordinate that
     * is only used for controling the spline and is not visualized.
     * @param index The index of control point p0, where p0, p1, p2, and p3 are used in
     * order to create a curve between p1 and p2.
     * @param pointsPerSegment The total number of uniformly spaced interpolated points to
     * calculate for each segment. The larger this number, the smoother the resulting
     * curve.
     * @return the list of coordinates that define the CatmullRom curve between the points
     * defined by index+1 and index+2.
     */
    public static List<Coordinate> interpolate(List<Coordinate> points, int index, int pointsPerSegment) {
        List<Coordinate> result = new ArrayList<>();
        double[] x = new double[4];
        double[] y = new double[4];
        double[] time = new double[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            x[i] = points.get(index + i).x;
            y[i] = points.get(index + i).y;
            time[i] = i;
        }

        double tstart;
        double tend;
        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            double dx = x[i] - x[i - 1];
            double dy = y[i] - y[i - 1];
            total += Math.pow(dx * dx + dy * dy, .25);
            time[i] = total;
        }
        tstart = time[1];
        tend = time[2];

        int segments = pointsPerSegment - 1;
        result.add(points.get(index + 1));
        for (int i = 1; i < segments; i++) {
            double xi = interpolate(x, time, tstart + (i * (tend - tstart)) / segments);
            double yi = interpolate(y, time, tstart + (i * (tend - tstart)) / segments);
            result.add(new Coordinate(xi, yi));
        }
        result.add(points.get(index + 2));
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Unlike the other implementation here, which uses the default "uniform" treatment of
     * t, this computation is used to calculate the same values but introduces the ability
     * to "parameterize" the t values used in the calculation. This is based on Figure 3
     * from http://www.cemyuksel.com/research/catmullrom_param/catmullrom.pdf
     *
     * @param p An array of double values of length 4, where interpolation occurs from p1
     * to p2.
     * @param time An array of time measures of length 4, corresponding to each p value.
     * @param t the actual interpolation ratio from 0 to 1 representing the position
     * between p1 and p2 to interpolate the value.
     * @return
     */
    public static double interpolate(double[] p, double[] time, double t) {
        double L01 = p[0] * (time[1] - t) / (time[1] - time[0]) + p[1] * (t - time[0]) / (time[1] - time[0]);
        double L12 = p[1] * (time[2] - t) / (time[2] - time[1]) + p[2] * (t - time[1]) / (time[2] - time[1]);
        double L23 = p[2] * (time[3] - t) / (time[3] - time[2]) + p[3] * (t - time[2]) / (time[3] - time[2]);
        double L012 = L01 * (time[2] - t) / (time[2] - time[0]) + L12 * (t - time[0]) / (time[2] - time[0]);
        double L123 = L12 * (time[3] - t) / (time[3] - time[1]) + L23 * (t - time[1]) / (time[3] - time[1]);
        double C12 = L012 * (time[2] - t) / (time[2] - time[1]) + L123 * (t - time[1]) / (time[2] - time[1]);
        return C12;
    }

}
```