# Smooth Interpolation between two points

Tags: interpolation, curve, points, smoothing, cubic

i am trying to interpolate in a mesh between points. I did some research and found few solutions, but all of them produce weird results for me. I tried Cosinus and Cubic interpolation, but whole mesh gets tiny waves in it instead of being smooth.

I tried this

```
 mu2 = mu*mu;
   a0 = y3 - y2 - y0 + y1;
   a1 = y0 - y1 - a0;
   a2 = y2 - y0;
   a3 = y1;

   return(a0*mu*mu2+a1*mu2+a2*mu+a3);
```

from here : http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/

i got all the points i need and all should be working, but it isnt. I spent a lot of time debugging it and only thing i found to be a problem is that it seems that mu ( regular t from 0.0 - 1.0 in interpolation ) starts at 0.0 at P1 as it should, but at 1.0 it is at P3, while it should be at P2 ( points P0, P1, P2, P3, where interpolation should happen between P1 and P2 )

If there is any other better simple way how to do interpolation between two points, please let me know. I dont want to do bezier curves or anything like that with controls points. I just have two points and i can use one more point on each side like in the example above.

Thanks for any help
Luke

Comment: It looks like you might want to use a [Catmull-Rom spline](http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/catmull/).

Comment: thank you sir, that worked like a charm. I would mark this as correct answer if i could.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that a Catmull-Rom spline would be suitable for your data.

As an example of implementing it in VB.NET:

```vb
Module Module1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' A class for a 2-D point and operations on it.
    ''' </summary>
    Class PointD
        Property X As Double
        Property Y As Double

        Public Shared Operator +(p1 As PointD, p2 As PointD) As PointD
            Return New PointD(p1.X + p2.X, p1.Y + p2.Y)
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator -(p As PointD) As PointD
            Return New PointD(-p.X, -p.Y)
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator -(p1 As PointD, p2 As PointD) As PointD
            Return New PointD(p1.X - p2.X, p1.Y - p2.Y)
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator *(a As Double, p As PointD) As PointD
            Return New PointD(a * p.X, a * p.Y)
        End Operator

        Public Shared Operator *(p As PointD, a As Double) As PointD
            Return New PointD(a * p.X, a * p.Y)
        End Operator

        'TODO: (Optional) Add methods for magnitude, cross product and dot product.

        Public Sub New()
            ' empty contructor
        End Sub

        Public Sub New(x As Double, y As Double)
            Me.X = x
            Me.Y = y
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            ' use the N3 format string for tidiness in this example
            Return $"({X:N3}, {Y:N3})"
        End Function

    End Class

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Ordinary Catmull-Rom interpolation.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="t">Vary from 0.0 to 1.0 to get an interpolated point between data points p1 and p2.</param>
    ''' <param name="p0">The first control point.</param>
    ''' <param name="p1">The first data point.</param>
    ''' <param name="p2">The second data point.</param>
    ''' <param name="p3">The second control point.</param>
    ''' <returns>The interpolated point.</returns>
    Function CatmullRomInterpolate(t As Double, p0 As PointD, p1 As PointD, p2 As PointD, p3 As PointD) As PointD
        ' this is the regular Catmull-Rom spline
        ' other ways of treating it can be found at:
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489736/catmull-rom-curve-with-no-cusps-And-no-self-intersections
        Return 0.5 * ((2 * p1) +
            t * (p2 - p0) +
            Math.Pow(t, 2) * (2 * p0 - 5 * p1 + 4 * p2 - p3) +
            Math.Pow(t, 3) * (3 * (p1 - p2) + p3 - p0))

    End Function


    Sub Main()
        ' some sample data which will produce a symmetrical wave shape...
        Dim p0 As New PointD(-1, 1)
        Dim p1 As New PointD(0, 0)
        Dim p2 As New PointD(1, 0)
        Dim p3 As New PointD(2, -1)

        For t = 0.0 To 1.0 Step 0.1
            Console.WriteLine(CatmullRomInterpolate(t, p0, p1, p2, p3))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Depending on what you need, you might find [Catmull-rom curve with no cusps and no self-intersections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9489736/1115360) useful.