# Minimum number of control points in CatmulRomSpline libgdx

Tags: libgdx, catmull-rom-curve

I am using the [CatmullRomSpline](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-&-Splines) class of libgdx for creating a smooth curve passing through three points.  Basically I want to place coins between two platforms in a curved path. For that I followed the following algorithm [image: reference image]

- Take the end top point of first platform as the first control point;
- Take the middle point bw top end of first platform and top start of second platform , add a little height to it in y direction and take this point as second control point.
- Take the top start point as second platform as third control point.

Now when I am trying to create a smooth path for my coin generation using these three control points, I just get one value what so ever t is use (CatmullRomSpline uses a float value t as parameter which has to vary bw 0 and 1).

Is there something I am missing . Is it that I need to provide more control points ?

Comment: There's a good explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085617/catmull-rom-splines-how-do-they-work

Comment: Try duplicating the first and last point (or even better, add points below the first and last point)